# Ruby on Rails script/console printing more than expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple model setup in my Ruby on Rails app.  (User {name, username, lat, lon}) and am writing a basic extension to the model.  I would like the method to return users within a certain distance.  It all works just fine in the page view, but as I am debugging I would like to work through some testing using the script/console.

My question:  It seems to be printing to the screen the entire result set when I run it from the command line and script/console.

My model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def distance_from(aLat, aLon)
    Math.sqrt((69.1*(aLat - self.lat))**2 + (49*(aLon - self.lon))**2 )
  end 


  def distance_from_user(aUser)
    distance_from(aUser.lat, aUser.lon)
  end

  def users_within(distance)
    close_users = []
    users = User.find(:all)
    users.each do |u|
        close_users << u if u.distance_from_user(self) < distance
    end
    return close_users
  end
end
```

and from the command line I am running

```
>> u = User.find_by_username("someuser")
>> print u.users_within(1)
```

So, I guess I would like to know why it's printing the whole result set, and if there is a way to suppress it so as to only print what I want?

Comment: Well, I'd like a print of about 10 or so Users who fall within a mile.  Not the 1000 users that are in the db.

Comment: Looks quite strange to me. Are you sure that User "someuser" has `lat` and `lon` fields set? Maybe try to see what is happening when you do somethings like this: `u.User.find_by_username("someuser"); v = User.find(200); v.distance_from_user(u);`.
And as @Salil sugested, it is bad idea to do it the way you proposed. Even if you won't write single query to get all records you are interested in, it's better to use `find_in_batches` than `find.all`

Comment: Yes, I know it's not the most optimized way of doing it, I am using this as an example for teaching Ruby on Rails and the power of the script/console, but it's hardly usable when it dumps all this out to the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the console interface of the Ruby application evaluates each line as though it were entered from the console.

I would have expected it to some encapsulation of the scripts but it makes sense as it is being interpreted on the fly by the ruby interactive console line.

And to clarify as to the prefered sql base solution, doing find_by_sql is frowned upon in most refereces I have found.  The SQL based solution that I reccomend is

```
def f
  User.find(:all, :conditions => ["sqrt(pow(69.1*(lat - ?),2) + pow(49*(lon - ?),2)) < 1", lat.to_s,lon.to_s])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you should handle it using a mysql query.
it's not good practise to pull all data from the database perofrm on them and show top 10 data out of them.
do something like following.

```
User.find_by_sql("select u.*, 
          (((69.1*(aLat - self.lat))**2 + (49*(aLon - self.lon))**2 ) < 100")) as distance
          from users u
          where u.username='someuser' and
          distance > 100 order by distance DESC LIMIT 10)
```

Above query is just an example but it's always good practice to do something like above.

Comment: I know that is generally the case.  In fact I have done load testing with varying recordset sizes up to a 50M or so users.  In PHP the performance is about 1:3 between sql vs server script.  There are often circumstances where the best way to do the comparison is within the method.  So, my question still stands, why does it print all the results to the screen